# Select types conditionally

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a monorepo with two apps: client and merchant. They share a common stack navigator - authentication, which is nested inside the root navigator.
To set screen props for the authentication navigator, I need to use the root navigator, which is specific for each app.
Also, to avoid duplicates, the authentication navigator, types, and screens are in a package.
In one of the screens I have `export const RequestEmailLinkScreen = ({ route, navigation }: Props) => {`
But the question here is how to load the correct Props (clent vs merchant) based on the app used?
I do have `const appSlug = Constants.expoConfig?.slug;`
So I was thinking to do something like this:

```
import { MyScreenProps as ClientMyScreenProps } from '../../../types/client';
import { MyScreenProps as MerchantMyScreenProps} from '../../../types/merchant';

const appSlug = Constants.expoConfig?.slug;

type Props = appSlug === "client" ? ClientMyScreenProps : MerchantMyScreenProps;

export const MyScreen = ({ route, navigation }: Props) => {
```

But this is not right.
How do I do that and can you think of a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to get a compile time value (the type) with a runtime value (the slug).

I'm afraid this is not possible with your current code.

I suggest you accept both Props and resolve the app during runtime. For example:

```
import { MyScreenProps as ClientMyScreenProps } from '../../../types/client';
import { MyScreenProps as MerchantMyScreenProps} from '../../../types/merchant';

const appSlug = Constants.expoConfig?.slug; // Btw, you could also have an `undefined` here, take care of this
export const MyScreen = ({ route, navigation }: ClientMyScreenProps | MerchantMyScreenProps) => {
  if (appSlug === 'client') {
    // Do whatever you need on the client app
  } else {
    // Do whatever you need on the non-client app
  }
}
```

This, of course, means that you won't have typing assistance as, as I stated, you can't use a runtime value during compile time.

No matter what I think, it always depends on you doing a final runtime check to choose a path or another... If you really want to be able to run code as either one or another, you can always split the function in two and place a little code differentiating them both at the beginning. Take a look at [this playground to see what I mean](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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).

Comment: Appreciate it, but indeed this beats the whole point. It is indeed possible I will not be able to come up with a solution to this.

Comment: I've updated the answer with another option I just thought although it is not better than the previous one :-(

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because there seems to be no solution. Typescript is perhaps unable to conditionally load at runtime. Oh well. After hours of different test, I ended up with the same solution as yours, which is to shove both TS definitions into the component.